# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Item.h”': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a .cpp file called factory.cpp, that looks as follows: (just starting the program)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Item.h”
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

My item.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

Class Item{
public:
...

private:
...
};

#endif
```

When I try to compile I get the following error:
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Item.h”': No such file or directory.

I have checked, and both my cpp file and my header are located at the following directory:

c:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\factory\factory\

and just to be on the safe side I even added this directory to additional included directories, yet stil no success...
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 express, and would greatly appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: rewrite the ending double quote in #include "Item.h” I think it's not the right one.

Answer (score 4):

Your include is wrong, you must use ", but not ”. 
You have:

```
#include "Item.h”
```

You should have:

```
#include "Item.h"
```